# Rich Text Editor - Option to remove all style attributes

Tags: richtext-editor

How can I provide an option in the Rich Text Editor to remove all style attributes of the selected text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be available for you by default:

1. Click Show editor on field that your want to edit
2. Select tassel icon
3. Select Strip Css Formatting from dropdown menu
   [image]

If it is not available in your version/configuration, then you can enable it by [selecting HTML Editor Profile](https://andrey-vinda.tech.blog/2016/11/27/how-to-setup-rich-text-editor-in-sitecore-basics/).

1. Open template field on which you want to be able to remove style attributes
2. Set source field value to "/sitecore/system/Settings/Html Editor Profiles/Rich Text Full" (Or another, use link with explanation above)